# Unable to fix home nav's style compared to other navs in navbar

Tags: css, sitefinity

[image: Home menu]

Here's the issue which is making me go mad for a good half a day. Here, I'm unable to set that faint box border around the Home navigation item to none, similar to the other navigations. I've tried to set the border property for that Home's `<a>` element, the `<li>` which encloses that `<a>` to none, nothing works. I was using CDT to play around with that, even though it shows my style is being applied, no visible effect is observed.

I also tried setting the border color to different color for debugging purpose, it didn't work. Next, I tried to test for properties other than border, like box-shadow, background. None of them worked.

We're using Sitefinity CMS as the backend, which has templates. A web page is created by using one the pre-defined templates as the base, and then building up contents for the web page upon that base. I tried looking for anything which overrides or applies border, box-shadow, background for the navigations, I just found the correct ones, which was the same for our dev and stage environments. Kindly help me out on this.

Comment: Looks like the `box-shadow` property, maybe a linear gradient, not a border. -- *impossible* to tell without seeing HTML and CSS.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I found the issue, and it was by bootstrap. It was applying box-shadow and I had to override in my media query.